# Glide cannot load server image url

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

Trying to load images with similar URLs like this

```
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/content-office-e1931.appspot.com/o/usersData%2Fposts%2Fmedia_-KpGAURJbB33BKhTynV1?alt=media&token=26135949-a918-4572-9293-b639d43f04aa"
```

But glide shows logs

```
Load failed for  with size [360x360]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
```

Previous logs

```
Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor 
compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:compiler in your application 
and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules 
will be silently ignored
```

I can't understand why I should add AppGlideModule and etc just to load images. My code in Kotlin, I have added compiler dependency as below

```
 //image loader
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC1'
```

Here is how I call Glide

```
 fun bind(post: Post) {
    for ((k, v) in post.media) {
        Glide.with(itemView.context)
                .asBitmap()
                .apply(RequestOptions.encodeQualityOf(70))
                .apply(RequestOptions.overrideOf(width,width))
                .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
                .load(v.downloadPath)
                .into(image)
    }
}
```

I had tried attach a listener to see logs, what is happening when Glide tries to load image but I see only "Failed to load resource" nothing useful

Comment: Maybe related to this issue, https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2039

Comment: check u have loaded correct index and value in the for loop

Comment: @Nithinlal, definitely sure it is correct, as said first comment, it's really related to that issue.

Comment: Have you tried with another library like Picasso? Besides that, it may be related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156802/glide-cannot-load-server-image-url#comment77282799_45156802

Answer (score 3):

it's working with me :

```
Glide.with(itemView.context)
  .load(new URL(v.downloadPath))
  .into(image);
```

Comment: This may be the answer.  Would you mind expanding this with some context?  Why does this work instead of OP's code?  When future visitors land on your answer the will have an explanation of why it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know is this solution going work for everyone but in my case it worked !

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"


</application>
```

and try to load your image in this format

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(new URL(your_image))
.into(image)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your **url should not contain space at start and end**, even if their is any chances trim your url.

Answer (score 0):

Your image source URL is incorrect, please make sure it correct by the way check it using the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use This Strategy and You're Done.

```
Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load("Your Network Image Path")
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                    iv.setImageBitmap(resource);
                    iv.buildDrawingCache();
                }
                @Override
                public void onLoadCleared(@Nullable Drawable placeholder) { }
            });
```